# Develop a payout gateway?

Tags: android, iphone

Now I am in process of building an app which grants merchants access to sell their items through the app. Processing credit card payments from costumers is in the process and is quite logical how ever, I am battling the question of how to write a code/what service or platform to use to payout to the merchants automatically each month, any ideas of how I can start?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please take a minute to look at the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour as well as this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help on how to ask questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if the checkout company offers an api for mass checkouts, you will be able to send merchants their share every month or the interval that the api allows. Not every checkout company offers this though.